# eclipse debug configuration ignores -Dlog4j.debug setting, why?

Tags: eclipse, log4j

I want to know why my efforts to set a log4j config for a desktop application won't work. Many answers here suggest to first give the setting -Dlog4j.debug to the VM, for debugging purposes. On the command line this works. When I place this in the Run/Debug configurations.../VM arguments field, and click Debug, nothing shows in the Console View (which is correctly labeled after my configuration). Why?

Additional info: log4j.jar is in the build path settings, eclipse version is indigo 20110909

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to be using slf4j, and you haven't installed the `slf4j-log4j12-x.x.x.jar`, then the `-Dlog4j.debug` flag won't give any output, regardless of log4j being on the classpath. slf4j wants to have exactly one backend logger (as specified by exactly one backend jar file).

After I replaced `slf4j-jdk14-x.x.x.jar` with `slf4j-log4j12-x.x.x.jar`, all worked.